# XmbTextListToTextProperty result code -2 : error during executing cv2.imshow in .py file from a shell script

Tags: python, linux, bash, shell, opencv

I am trying to run a simple .py file with a video capturing code in it from a shell script. For this, I have used plain OpenCV. Now, I am calling this .py from a shell script. When I execute the shell script from the integrated terminal in VSCode, it works fine. But when the same .py file is executed from terminal i.e. outside VSCode, it throws up this in the terminal:

XmbTextListToTextProperty result code -2

and completes execution (i.e. captures frames from the webcam ) in spite of this appearing at on the terminal

test1.py is the .py that has the cv2 code and reading the frame from the webcam:

```
import cv2
img = None
vid = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
while True:
    _, img = vid.read()
    cv2.imshow("Frame", cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB))
    if cv2.waitKey(5) & 0xFF == ord('y'):
        break
vid.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

test.sh is the shell script I am using

```
#!/bin/bash
eval "$(conda shell.bash hook)"
conda activate facenet
python3 ./test1.py
```

On executing test.sh in Terminal (i.e. outside the integrated terminal in VSCode):

```
(base) pranjal@pranjal99:~/Projects/WhosThere$ ./test.sh 
XmbTextListToTextProperty result code -2
XmbTextListToTextProperty result code -2
XmbTextListToTextProperty result code -2
(base) pranjal@pranjal99:~/Projects/WhosThere$
```

**NOTE**: In spite of these errors appearing in the terminal, the code is executing accurately. Also, when executed in the Integrated Terminal in VSCode, it works fine i.e. it does NOT throw up these errors

After a lot of trials, I figured this anomaly is due to the line, although I don't have the slightest idea why

```
cv2.imshow("Frame", cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB))
```

On removing this line, no such errors appear in the terminal.

**EDIT**: On printing the shape of the frame that has been read we get the following in terminal (outside VSCode's Integrated terminal):

```
(480, 640, 3)
XmbTextListToTextProperty result code -2
XmbTextListToTextProperty result code -2
XmbTextListToTextProperty result code -2
(480, 640, 3)
(480, 640, 3)
(480, 640, 3)
(480, 640, 3)
(480, 640, 3)
(480, 640, 3)
(480, 640, 3)
(480, 640, 3)
(480, 640, 3)
(480, 640, 3)
(480, 640, 3)
(480, 640, 3)
(480, 640, 3)
(480, 640, 3)
(480, 640, 3)
(480, 640, 3)
(480, 640, 3)
(480, 640, 3)
(480, 640, 3)
(480, 640, 3)
(480, 640, 3)
(480, 640, 3)
(480, 640, 3)
(480, 640, 3)
(480, 640, 3)
(480, 640, 3)
(480, 640, 3)
(480, 640, 3)
(480, 640, 3)
(480, 640, 3)
(480, 640, 3)
(480, 640, 3)
(480, 640, 3)
(480, 640, 3)
(480, 640, 3)
(480, 640, 3)
(480, 640, 3)
(480, 640, 3)
(480, 640, 3)
(480, 640, 3)
(480, 640, 3)
(480, 640, 3)
(480, 640, 3)
(480, 640, 3)
(480, 640, 3)
(480, 640, 3)
(480, 640, 3)
(480, 640, 3)
(480, 640, 3)
(480, 640, 3)
(480, 640, 3)
(480, 640, 3)
(480, 640, 3)
```

It would be really helpful is someone could guide me in the correct direction to resolve these weird errors.

Comment: You are not handling the condition when your vid object has ni frames to read.  Check if a frame has been read and only then display it.

Comment: @ShubhamJaiswal I tried by adding `if ret == True:
        cv2.imshow("Frame", cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB))`.But unfortunately, it didnt work. Same error. Please correct me if i did something incorrectly about your suggestion

Comment: can you try this : cv2.VideoCapture(0, cv2.CAP_V4L)

Comment: @ShubhamJaiswal sorry. No luck.

Comment: can you confirm if you are reading the frames correctly by printing the image dimensions before calling cv2.imshow().

Comment: @ShubhamJaiswal I have added the output to the question. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Can't comment so writing here. Is it because of localisation?
Maybe you can type **locale** on your terminal and see what **LANG** is set. Try changing that to a different one and see.

I had a similar issue and I resolved it by changing the LANG value from "**en-IN**" to "**en_US.utf8**" and then restarting.

You can use this command to update it:

```
sudo update-locale LANG=name_of_locale_here
```